# How do you add to the Vim search history without opening a window?

Tags: vim

I am writing a function that acts like the `*` key but does not move the cursor.  Setting the current search pattern is easy:

```
let @/='...'
```

so `n` and `N` and even `//` work as expected.  But `*` also adds an entry to the search history.  The best I've come up with is:

```
silent! normal! q/"/p
```

but that opens the search history window briefly, which causes ugly flickering when I trigger the function.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You may want to look into Ingo Karkat's [SearchHighlighting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) plugin. Which does this plus a bit more. It also has links to other similar plugins which might be of use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [:help histadd()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#histadd())

```
histadd({history}, {item})              *histadd()*
        Add the String {item} to the history {history} which can be
        one of:                 *hist-names*
            "cmd"    or ":"   command line history
            "search" or "/"   search pattern history
            "expr"   or "="   typed expression history
            "input"  or "@"   input line history
            "debug"  or ">"   debug command history
        The {history} string does not need to be the whole name, one
        character is sufficient.
        If {item} does already exist in the history, it will be
        shifted to become the newest entry.
        The result is a Number: 1 if the operation was successful,
        otherwise 0 is returned.
```

When writing vimscript the info from [:help function-list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#function-list) can be very helpful (the entire chapter 41, actually).

Answer (score 1):

`:call histadd('/', 'foo')` then check your search history.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo I didn't add any further comment because @mMontu has already quoted the relevant text from `:h histadd`. So perhaps my answer should have instead been an edit of his answer?

Comment: thanks for your clarification Sir, you could edit the accepted answer or just add some explanation (in your words) in your answer. it's up to you. assume the author of the accepted answer, will delete his post or update it with different content, what is the best approach in this scenarios?